# Experimenting with Random Number Generation

Tags: javascript, html, random

The question I had here was: "How do you separate the values in a DTG into day, month, year, etc 9as integers) and then separate the digits of those numbers for calculations?"

This question is now answered. Thanks.

I'm looking for information on how to generate a calculation with the following conditions:

1. the module must be ran using HTML and JavaScript,
2. the module must get the current date and time as integers,
3. the module needs to calculate the generated numbers to get a 1 or 2 digit integer after the calculation is complete,
4. and the date and time must have the following conditions;

   - the date must be divided into separate numbers for year, month, and day
   - and the time must divided into separate numbers for hour, minute, second, and millisecond

Each number will either be 2 digits or 4 digits long. For example:

The module is to be written in HTML and JavaScript.

I call for date and time to get int day as dd, int month as mm, int year as yyyy, int hour as hh, int minute as mm, int second as ss, and int millisecond as ssss.

to show

day as a number 00, month as a number 00, year as a number 0000, hour as a number 00, minute as a number 00, second as a number 00, millisecond as a number 0000

I then need the module to perform a calculation using these numbers:

number 1 from first digit of day + second digit of day, number 2 from first digit of month + second digit of month, etc.

The purpose of this module is to add each number in the date and time to get a 1 or 2 digit number. If the result <= 2 digits, I can work with a 2 digit number. If the result >= 100, I need to further reduce it.

The concept is the numerology method of taking a series of numbers and reducing them down to a 1 digit number, but I can deal with 2 numbers for this experiment.

The experiment:

I am testing a methodology of random number generation by using the exact current date and time, down to the millisecond, to generate a current 1 or 2 digit number every millisecond. For testing purposes, we can work with seconds to see slower results return every 1 second.

The objective of the experiment is to get a random number that bypasses the traditional method of RNG, which creates a number not very randomly. The traditional method repeats the same numbers each time you run the module.

This method will create a new random number based on the current DTG every 1 millisecond, generating a new random number every time the module runs, and no pass can create the same random number unless the DTG comes to the exact same calculation (which is way more random than the built in RNG system in most software, despite the fact that the number is being created methodically and not randomly).

Intent with this project:

I want to utilize a system of RNG to create a 1 or 2 digit number that can be used on a sliding scale of 0-9 or 00-99, with the idea in mind of using this RNG engine to generate a random number every 1 millisecond for a game that utilizes RNG in other components.

For example:

The RNG Engine generates a number 0-9 or 00-99 every 1 millisecond. That number can now be used to determine hit or miss, chances for critical hits, chances for successful actions in a chance based mechanics, etc.

Building a complex system like those used by current game engines has proven very complex and problematic for me in the past, so i want to avoid those for now. This system, as far as I know, is not used or has not been used before. If it has, great, this should be easier. If not, the system can create random numbers at a fast pace and in a method that cannot be accurately cheated by people using timed attempts to hit a button at a specific time (as is done in many games). This method will be far too fast for any such physical attempts, and would require a computer to do it and the knowledge that the system is being used.

Like I said, this is an experiment. The fact that there may be better RNG tools out is irrelevant. I can deal with those later as needed. For now, I want to make this module as I have presented for testing purposes only. I need to run it in HTML first, and then I need to run it in JavaScript. Down the road I can work on PHP once I have tested a number of iterations.

So, what I should see is something like this: (and here begins the pseudo pseudo code)

```
<code>
    //NOTE: "~" and "..." represents repetitive iteration over the array, i.e. - I skip stuff.

    //var set
    int number_1(day);
    ~
    ~
    int number_7(millisecond);

    //Gets the DTG and returns the values.
    get DTG();

    //Gets the values from DTG and makes them individual integer values.
    set Perform(){
        number_1 = DTG(dd);
        number_2 = DTG(mm);
        ~
        ~
        number_7 = DTG(ssss);
    }

    //Conducts a calculation on those values.
    calc1(){
        number_1 = number_1(digit1) + number_1(digit2);
        number_2 = number_2(digit1) + number_2(digit2);
        ~
        ~
        number_7 = number_7(digit1) + number_7(digit2) + number_7(digit3) + number_7(digit4);
    }

    //Calculates the returned values [number_1-number_7].
    calc2(){
        int someNum = number_1 + number_2 + ... + number_7;
        if(someNum >= 100; reduce to a num < 100){
            code
        }
        return someNum(where someNum must be a number between 0-9 or 00-99);
    }

    //I use the calcs to get the numbers I need.
    int iNeedTheseNumbers perform calc1(get [number_1, ... , number_7]);
    int theseNumbersToOneNum perform calc2(get someNum);

    if(theseNumbersToOneNumber >= 100; reduce to num < 100){
        code;
    }

    //Return the 1 or 2 digit number.
    return theseNumbersToOneNumber;
</code>
```

Yes, I know this pseudo pseudo code is not great, it's been years since I did any of this stuff. I apologize for this, especially if it causes confusion. I tried to make it in a way that is easy to understand what I am trying to get, using terms and methods I can remember from my school days.

I'm sure you'll have questions, so feel free to ask.

Again, I am trying to make an RNG engine using both HTML and JavaScript separately, to generate a 1 or 2 digit number by performing addition on the values of the current DTG down to the millisecond, where the numbers used in the DTG are reduced down to make the 1 or 2 digit number.

For clarification on the numerology reference, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerology and scroll down to the Latin Alphabet system entry.

Comment: I have a question:  What's **your** question?

Comment: are you asking someone to write this for you?

Comment: @chester Problem -> SO Question -> MAGIC -> Working Solution

Comment: I just need to know how to get the date and time into individual numbers and how to add the first digit of a number to its second digit. I can figure the rest out no problem.

Comment: Are you looking for existing libraries using your proposed method? Or libraries delivering random numbers, so you can test against them?

Comment: Kenneth, using `new Date().getTime()` will get you the full date as an integer representing the milliseconds elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date. From there, you can just divide the number to get the pieces you need.

Comment: if there is a current method like this already made to do this, just point the way. That would make this process way easier. Otherwise, I am trying to build this to test some ideas i am working on. I've used built in RNG engines before and they just don't make random numbers random enough. And I want to avoid the big engines used by developers, because it will take too long to RE them for my purposes.

Comment: **The traditional method repeats the same numbers each time you run the module.** Not of you change the seed of the RNG. A common way to do that is to use the current time as the seed.

Comment: Barmar, I've tried that before and even made some hefty programs just dedicated to making random numbers. Not really what I am looking to recreate.

Comment: *"I just need to know how to get the date and time into individual numbers and how to add the first digit of a number to its second digit. I can figure the rest out no problem."* - So you could [edit] your question to delete 95% of your giant wall of text and just ask specifically about this.

Comment: nnnnnn, yes. i could. but, then there would be trolls saying stuff like "why not use a RNG that is already out?" And I would have to explain all this stuff anyways.

Comment: @Kenneth - it would be helpful if you edited your question and put your actual question near the top of what you've written.  Then go on to explain the details.

Comment: devlin carnate, I'm going to do that. I was looking for a way to close this question tho, cause I have my answer already.

Comment: @Kenneth Take care to correctly spell *JavaScript* so as to avoid search collision with *Java*. [JavaScriptIsNotJava.io](http://javascriptisnotjava.io)

Comment: @Kenneth - you can close the question by selecting the answer as the answer (the checkmark near the top of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

To split date up into pieces

```
var now = new Date();
var d = now.getDate();
var m = now.getMonth();
var y = now.getFullYear();
var h = now.getHours();
var mm = now.getMinutes();
var s = now.getSeconds();
var ms = now.getMilliseconds();
```

To split a number into digits you can do something like this

```
var digits = new Array();
var sNumber = number.toString();

for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    digits.push(sNumber.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is not an RNG, it's a hash function of the time.

RNGs are like Crypto: unless you have a degree in math and/or have studied the issue in great detail, never "roll your own". Even a poorly implemented RNG or Crypto algorithm is likely to be better than anything you might come up with on your own. And of course, follow the instructions of the algorithm carefully: for example, choose an algorithm suited to your use (secure ones for Crypto, faster long-period ones for simulations), and seed it properly (such as from the time--but only once, or else you're back to just a hash function).